# SQL Statement in PHP fails during execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to update my MariaDB with PHP.

As far as I know the statement itself works, but the execute doesnt.

Heres my Code:

And yes, the Variables are declared :)

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname","user","pass");
 
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE dname SET status = :status, text = :text WHERE id = :id");

 if ($statement->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':status' => $status, ':text' => $text))){
        echo "{success:true}";
 } else {
        echo "{success:false}";
 }
```

I do have success:false, but nothing from the if above (!statement).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is `dname` in the UPDATE-statement the table or is it againg the database name `dbname`?
Can you provide the error-message and the DB-schema?

Comment: dname is the table name. Sadly i don tknow how to get the error message, since its a 200 Status Code.

Comment: May try print the error on false with [errorInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php)